# Static Frontpage

Tags: 8, routes

I'm a seasoned front-end developer and extremely new to Drupal.
I've just created a new instance of Drupal 8 and all I am trying to do is create a static one pager for a client who needs a simple web presence before building the full Drupal8 site in the new year.

Using a purchased theme, all I need is to create and route a static homepage, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a node of the type page and fill it with the static html:

```
/node/add/page
```

Then go to

```
/admin/config/system/site-information
```

and configure the "Default Front Page". If the page you've created earlier is the first node, then this is `/node/1`.

Comment: Thanks 4k4, I've seen this already, I was thinking there might have been a different way in doing this, but if this is the best way, then great!

Comment: That's how you do it in UI. You can do more adjustments in the theme in a page template with the name `page--front.html.twig`. You could use this also for static html.

Comment: Also the Drupal 8 User Guide has a chapter that goes over content creation and setting it to the front page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/content-chapter.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the easiest way to make a static (but CMS editable) frontpage is to make a Basic Page node (`page`) and set that URL at the frontpage in the CMS settings (admin/config/system/site-information). For example, `node/1`.

We tend to do this with a dedicated custom node type so that we can add extra fields (eg an image field that can be styles for a carousel, or entity references for promoting frontpage blog posts, etc).

Comment: Thanks NIck, same as 4k4's answer and again, if this is the best way then thanks. Going to mark his as correct answer as he was first to answer. So close :)

Comment: Heh - he beat me to it by a minute :)